# Go - How increase maximum Stdin input length?

Tags: go

What's the recommended way to allow more than 1024 characters when reading from standard input in Go?

For example, this code using `bufio.Scanner` has a maximum input length of 1024.

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    scanner.Scan()
    input := scanner.Text()
    fmt.Println(input)
}
```

Update after some suggested answers...
Sorry guys - I must still be doing something wrong, or misstated the question.  I tried both suggestions and still see the same issue.  Below is an updated version of the code.  The symptom is that the scanner won't accept input after the 1024th character. e.g. Try to run this then paste in a string that's 1025 characters long, and it'll stop accepting input after character 1024.

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    var buffer bytes.Buffer
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)

    for {
        done := scanner.Scan()
        buffer.WriteString(scanner.Text())
        if done == true {
            if scanner.Err() != nil {
                log.Fatal("Error scanning input")
            }
            break
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(buffer.String())
}
```

Comment: The [maximum scanner token size](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#pkg-constants) is 64k. There's an [example of how to use the Scanner in the docs](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#example_Scanner_lines)

Comment: You can't test this by pasting text into a terminal. In cooked mode the tty has a hard coded input buffer in the kernel, usually 4096 on Linux and 1024 on Darwin.

Comment: Argh - thanks JimB.  I was unaware of this, and that's what was tripping me up.  It was confusing because my terminal tool (iTerm on Darwin) allows more than 1024 chars when not running as part of a command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem with this code is that the return value of scanner.Scan is not `true` if the scanner is done, but `true` if the scanner is not done.

While we're fixing that, let's tidy up another thing, since you don't need to use

```
if done == true
```

but can simply do

```
if done
```

Also, remember that `done = Scanner.Text()`, and serves as the terminating condition, and we can tidy up the code really nicely with:

```
for scanner.Scan() { // This does what you want, looping until scanner
                     // is no longer true.
    buffer.WriteString(scanner.Text())
}
if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {           // Let's hold on to err...
    log.Fatalf("Error scanning input: %s", err) // and use it here.
}
```

You get to discard a lot of lines, and you only check Err() once at the end of the loop. No need to use break.

Hope that works for you, and send me a line if you need something else.

Edit: Two more things to be aware of.

1) `bufio.Scanner.Scan()` will be eating all your separator tokens. Maybe that's okay, or maybe you want to keep adding them back in.

2) `bufio.Scanner.Scan()` may panic if your SplitFunc is wrong, or someone is crafting poor input for your SplitFunc, and `bytes.Buffer.WriteString()` may panic if the buffer gets too large. If you're using these in a production system, make sure that you handle these panics in whatever way makes sense.

Comment: Marking this as the answer because it cleans up the sample code nicely, so thanks for that.  JimB's comment in the question was also my problem. i.e. This situation: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131105/how-to-read-over-4k-input-without-new-lines-on-a-terminal

Answer (score 5):

You are ignoring the return value of `scanner.Scan()` which is a `bool` indicating whether you have reached the end.

Specifically:

> It returns false when the scan stops, either by reaching the end of
>   the input or an error. After Scan returns false, the Err method will
>   return any error that occurred during scanning, except that if it was
>   io.EOF, Err will return nil.

So you need to continue running `scanner.Scan()` in a loop, until it returns false, then check `.Err()` to ensure you didn't stop scanning because of a non-EOF error.

Comment: Thanks sberry - I tried the suggestion and am still having a problem.  If you have time please see my updated code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this instead of using `Scanner`...

```
reader := bufio.NewReaderSize(os.Stdin, 65536)
line, isPrefix, err := reader.ReadLine()
```

Write a helper function to keep reading until you've read a complete line...

```
func ReadLine(reader *bufio.Reader) (string, error) {
    result := ""
    for {
        line, isPrefix, err := reader.ReadLine()
        if err != nil {
            return result, err
        }
        result += string(line)
        if !isPrefix {
            return result, nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ReadString or ReadBytes does this for you (from the ReadLine doc: "Most callers should use ReadBytes('\n') or ReadString('\n') instead or use a Scanner.")

Comment: Thanks FogleBird - I tried a variation of your suggestion and still had the same issue as I mentioned above.